# Syntax error with quotes in PHP (mouseover and image source)

Tags: php, quotes, onmouseover

I'm trying to include the **onmouseover function** with an image using **this.src='url'** in a PHP array.

I don't know if there is another way to call the image source without using single quotes, because it closes the HTML in that line.

```
$botons = array(
    array(
            'dia'=>1,
            'item'=>'<a href="#"><img src="/img/formula.png" onmouseover="this.src='/img/formula_over.png';" onmouseout="this.src='/img/formula.png';"></a>'
        ),
    );
```

I think I've tried everything... Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: Escape your quotes...

Comment: Thank you @Rizier123, I tried but it doesn't work escaping any quotes

Comment: You have 3 answers and all are telling you to escape your string. Now do you think all 3 are wrong, or maybe you don't show us something. (real code, error messages, ...)

Comment: My problem. Of course it works escaping the string. I was editing for day 1 (Monday), and today is day 7 (Sunday) [dia]. So I didn't see any changes. I'm sorry...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to ensure you escape the single quotes using backslashes:

```
$botons = array(
    array(
            'dia'=>1,
            'item'=>'<a href="#"><img src="/img/formula.png" onmouseover="this.src=\'/img/formula_over.png\';" onmouseout="this.src=\'/img/formula.png\';"></a>'
        ),
    );
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I had already tried escaping single quotes this way but it doesn't work... but thank you!

Comment: Are there any errors in your JavaScript console in your browser?

Comment: Stupid question, sorry. Of course it works. I was editing the array for "dia" DAY=1 (Monday) and today is DAY=7 (Sunday) so I wasn't seeing any changes. Anyway, thank you for your fast answers!

Answer (score 0):

Try to escape your quote, like the following.

```
'item' => '<a href="#"><img src="/img/formula.png" onmouseover="this.src=\'/img/formula_over.png\';" onmouseout="this.src=\'/img/formula.png\';"></a>'
```

Comment: Thanks, but I had already tried escaping single quotes this way and it doesn't work...

Comment: Saying something does not work is not useful to us. You should give more detail, like what do you see, is there any error message, etc...

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape from quote with '\'

```
        $botons = array(
         array(
          'dia'=>1,
          'item'=>'<a href="#"><img src="/img/formula.png" onmouseover="this.src=\'/img/formula_over.png\';" onmouseout="this.src=\'/img/formula.png\';"></a>'
    ),
```